# I can't display both Persian and English texts together in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecylcerView which loads it's data from an external server. And each of my items have a TextView. My problem is that **some** of my items don't have their related values for TextView when both English and Persian texts are used, and it shows nothing in the TextView. But it perfectly works fine when just one language, either English or Persian is used. By one language I mean all of the data in adapter be in one language not just one item.
Besides, my adapter gets it's data from external server, so I can't store my texts in /res folder. In addition, getText() in my code always shows the correct value.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if(viewHolder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
        final CategoryItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        String itemName = mItems.get(i).getName();

        //This line of code doesn't work for some items when both English and Arabic texts are used
        ((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).dsc.setText(itemName);

        //This line of code shows the correct values at all times
        System.out.println("itemName " + ((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).dsc.getText());

    }else{
        ((ProgressViewHolder)viewHolder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

As shown in the picture, there are some items which have empty TextView. The three values for empty items of this picture should be: bb, سلام , bbسلام

[image]

Comment: Why don't to use a custom ViewHolder instead RecyclerView.ViewHolder and dont use ((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder)?

Comment: sorry i maen to use a custom ViewHolder instead RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Comment: Because I have two ViewHolders which show two different things. I want to choose which one to show in the method. How can I choose between the two with one custom ViewHolder?

Comment: is it just the rows that show both arabic and english that don't work?

Comment: Ok. if you want i can show how)

Comment: @V.Kalyuzhnyu yes please show me, thanks.

Comment: @ootinii some items are just English and others are just Arabic, but there is no different, they are not shown at all. But there are some other items with the same pattern which are always displayed.

Comment: when you debug, do you see those values get set on the textviews?

Comment: @ootinii By debug you mean ui debug using Hierarchy Viewer? or just a simple Log? By logging yes I can see those values, but the only problem is just rendering on the screen. I don't know how to debug using Hierarchy Viewer, do you have any idea?

Comment: I just mean, put a breakpoint in your code at this line

((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).dsc.setText(itemName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching I figured out that my TextViews become visible after pressing Request Layout button in Hierarchy Viewer tool in Android Studio. So, I added one line to my code after setText()

`((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).dsc.requestLayout();`

And after that, everything worked fine.

I would be really thankful If anyone could explain the reason.

Answer (score 1):

A short example of multiple viewholders.

May be after this your code will be clearer

```
public class yourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //here is the place where viewholder may choose
    return position;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ItemViewHolder(...);
         case 1: return new ProgressViewHolder(...);
         ...
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have used. I posted just my onBindViewHolder method.